# Playing RTP Video Stream with HTML5-Video-Tag

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video, rtp

I am sending RTP video data from an Android phone to my computer. The RTP streaming works, proven with `ffplay`.

Now I'm trying to receive and display the stream inside Chrome (63.0.3239.84, Win10, 64Bit). I receive the RTP packets with `node.js` and pass them to all connected users with help of `socket.io`.

To display the video in an HTML5 `<video>`-tag, I tried a similar approach as [the example in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/MediaSource#Examples) of the MediaSource API. This is, what i've tried to append the video data on the fly:

```js
var socket    = io();
var ms        = new MediaSource();
var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42C01E"';
var queue     = [];
var video     = document.querySelector('video');

// receiving the rtp-packets from android, forwarded by nodes socket.io
socket.on('video-fragment', function(fragment) {
  queue.push(fragment.slice(11)); // cutting of rtp header to get plain NAL units
});

video.src = URL.createObjectURL(ms);

var timeout = 500;
var appendChunk = function() {
  if(queue.length > 0) {
    timeout = 500;
    var append = function() {
      var sb = ms.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
      sb.appendBuffer(queue.shift());
      sb.addEventListener('updateend', function() {
        if(video.paused) {
          console.log("try to start video");
          video.play();
        }

        appendChunk();
      });
      ms.removeSourceBuffer(sb);
    };
    if(ms.readyState == "open") {
      append();
    } else {
      ms.addEventListener('sourceopen', function() {
        appendChunk();
      });
    }
  } else {
    setTimeout(appendChunk, timeout); // try again after some timeout...
    timeout *= 2;
  }
}
appendChunk(); // start recursive call
```

```html
<video></video>
```

However, I don't get any errors from my video-object. If I close the MediaSource at some point with `ms.endOfStream()` and try to start the video after that, I get a MediaError with code `4: DEMUXER_ERROR_COULD_NOT_OPEN`.

Any suggestions? Am I somehow on the right way? Or is this kind of video streaming not possible in Chrome and the only way of "live streaming" would be with using a playlist and video-file-chunks?

Answer (score 0):

The browser only supports video in an mp4 (or webm) container. It does not support the rtp protocol. It must be repackaged to a format the browser supports.

Comment: So I can't remove the RTP header manually and use the NAL Unit stream as video input?

Comment: Removing an RTP Header doesn’t make it an mp4 fragment.